# R calculate raster cell size in map units

Tags: raster, r

I have a `RasterLayer` and would like to know the cell size. I haven't find any function in the packages :-S . Does someone have an idea ?

info about the `RasterLayer`

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 40, 40, 1600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0001106628, 0.0001106628  (x, y)
extent      : 3.061558, 3.065984, 42.5269, 42.53132  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 33  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `?area` function.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()  ## boilerplate longlat raster
ar <- area(r)  ## applies a correction for latitude, to km2
```

Comment: thank you mdsummer, obviosly I in wgs84... how can I have informations in meters?

Comment: @delaye, well, one thing that comes to mind is to convert kilometers to meters.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the defined resolution of a raster cell by using `res(my_raster_layer)`. Output is in map units. To obtain an area out of this, take the product:

```
my_raster_resolution <- res(my_raster_layer)
prod(my_raster_resolution) # multiplies the two instances of the resolution vector
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use `gArea` from **rgeos** for such kind of operations since I'm typically interested in a single value rather than an entire raster layer with area information. To get area information in meters, I would recommend projecting your raster (which is obviously located somewhere in France) to [EPSG:32631 (UTM zone 31N)](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-31n/) before transforming it to 'SpatialPolygons*'. From the latter, you can then easily retrieve the area of the sub-polygons.

```
## raster template
library(raster)

ext <- extent(c(42.5269, 42.53132, 3.061558, 3.065984))
rst <- raster(crs = "+init=epsg:4326", ext = ext, 
              nrows = 10, ncols = 10)

## project raster tu utm-31n and convert to polygons
rst_prj <- projectRaster(rst, crs = "+init=epsg:32631")
spy_prj <- rasterToPolygons(rst_prj)

## calculate polygon area 
library(rgeos)

gArea(spy_prj[1, ])
[1] 4032.24
```

Note that `area` from the **raster** package (as suggested by @mdsumner) works as well, i.e.

```
> area(rst_prj)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 12, 12, 144  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 63.6, 63.4  (x, y)
extent      : 5287874, 5288637, 439223, 439983.8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:32631 +proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 4032.24, 4032.24  (min, max)
```

but throwns a warning since `rst_prj` does not have longitude/latitude coordinates.

```
Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  This function is only useful for Raster* objects with a longitude/latitude coordinates
```

Comment: There's no point to convert to polygon after warping since every pixel is the same size in that coordinate system, by definition. It's impossible to answer this generally with a concise solution since there are so many details that matter about where and how extensive etc., but it's more sensible to convert to polygon from the source raster, and use the `n` option in `rasterToPolygons`, and then project, to ensure sufficient vertices to carry the polygons into the new coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Horrible quick approximation using raster properties, use with caution and only on projected datasets, and think very carefully about what you plan to do with the result:

```
cell_area <- abs((rlyr@extent@ymax - rlyr@extent@ymin) / rlyr@nrows *
  (rlyr@extent@xmax - rlyr@extent@xmin) / rlyr@ncols)
```

The only time I've ever done this is to approximate the number of raster cells intersecting a polygon (polygon area / cell area), because raster::extract was too slow and I didn't need a precise result.